# How to query current week & current month report by using LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datetime, windows-phone-7, summary

I am developing window phone 7 application in silverlight. I am new to the silverlight. I am also new to LINQ to XML. In my application the user select the date & submit some transaction details into the application. The details gets stored in XML File. I am using the custom date control in my application for the date selection as follows

```
        private void DatePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            AppObj = Application.Current as App;
            AppObj.date = (DateTime)EntryDate.Value;         

        }
```

Then the value of AppObj.date gets stored in the XML file. Sometimes I use the DateTime.Now to store the date in the XML File. Now I want to generate the report of submitted transaction details by querying through LINQ to XML. I want to generate the report for today's date, current week & current month. For today's date report I am using the following code

```
public class TransactionList : List<Transaction>
{
    public void GetTransactionObjects(String strXMLFile, int Currency_ID, int TransactionType_ID)
    {            
        XDocument doc = null;
        XMLFileManager XMLDocObj = new XMLFileManager();
        doc = XMLDocObj.LoadXMLFile(strXMLFile);

        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        var vTransaction = doc.Descendants("Transaction")
                          .Where(x => ((DateTime)x.Element("Current_Date")).Date == today) 
                          .Where(x => x.Element("TransactionType_ID").Value == TransactionType_ID.ToString())
                          .Where(x => x.Element("Currency_ID").Value == Currency_ID.ToString())                              
                           .Select(x => new Transaction(x));
        this.Clear();
        AddRange(vTransaction);           

    }
}
```

The Transaction class contains the following constructor.

```
    public Transaction(XElement xElement)
    {
        Transaction_ID = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("Transaction_ID").Value.ToString());
        TransactionType_ID = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("TransactionType_ID").Value.ToString());
        Alphabet_ID = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("Alphabet_ID").Value.ToString());
        ID = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("ID").Value.ToString());
        SubCategory_ID = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("SubCategory_ID").Value.ToString());
        Item_ID = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("Item_ID").Value.ToString());
        Currency_ID = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("Currency_ID").Value.ToString());
        InputTypeMethod_ID = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("InputTypeMethod_ID").Value.ToString());          
        Principle = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("InputTypeMethod_ID").Value.ToString());
        Interest = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("Interest").Value.ToString());
        ROI = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("InputTypeMethod_ID").Value.ToString());
        Amount = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("Amount").Value.ToString());
        //Current_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(xElement.Element("Current_Date").Value.ToString());
        Current_Date = ((DateTime)xElement.Element("Current_Date")).Date;
    }
```

In the XML File the value gets stored for date & time. The value gets stored as follows

```
  <Transactions>
      <Transaction>
        <Transaction_ID>0</Transaction_ID>
        <TransactionType_ID>0</TransactionType_ID>
        <Alphabet_ID>3</Alphabet_ID>
        <ID>0</ID>
        <SubCategory_ID>0</SubCategory_ID>
        <Item_ID>0</Item_ID>
        <Currency_ID>3</Currency_ID>
        <InputTypeMethod_ID>0</InputTypeMethod_ID>
        <Principle>0</Principle>
        <Interest>0</Interest>
        <ROI>0</ROI>
        <Amount>5000</Amount>
        <Current_Date>2010-12-31T18:08:23.433+05:30</Current_Date>
      </Transaction>
    </Transactions>
```

Look at the node

2010-12-31T18:08:23.433+05:30

The date format is yyyy-mm-dd.

Now how should I write the following query to get all the submitted transaction details for current week as well as current month ?

```
var vTransaction = doc.Descendants("Transaction")
                      .Where(x => ((DateTime)x.Element("Current_Date")).Date == today) 
                      .Where(x => x.Element("TransactionType_ID").Value == TransactionType_ID.ToString())
                      .Where(x => x.Element("Currency_ID").Value == Currency_ID.ToString())                              
                      .Select(x => new Transaction(x));
```

Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ? If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will give the current week summary  :

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek), // prev sunday 00:00
endDate = startDate.AddDays(7); // next sunday 00:00

var vTransaction = from x in doc.Descendants("Transaction")
                               where ((DateTime)x.Element("Current_Date")).Date >= startDate
                               && ((DateTime)x.Element("Current_Date")).Date < endDate
                               where x.Element("TransactionType_ID").Value == TransactionType_ID.ToString() 
                               select new Transaction(x);
```

The Following code will give the current month summary

```
int CurrentYear = DateTime.Today.Year;
int CurrentMonth = DateTime.Today.Month;

DateTime startDate = new DateTime(CurrentYear, CurrentMonth, 1);
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddMinutes(-1);

var vTransaction = from x in doc.Descendants("Transaction")
                                   where ((DateTime)x.Element("Current_Date")).Date >= startDate
                                   && ((DateTime)x.Element("Current_Date")).Date < endDate
                                   where x.Element("TransactionType_ID").Value == TransactionType_ID.ToString()
                                   select new Transaction(x);
```

OR both the queries can be wriiten for the current week of selected date & current month of selected date as follows

```
public void GetCurrentWeekSummary(String strXMLFile, int TransactionType_ID, DateTime selectedDate)
{
                XDocument doc = null;
                XMLFileManager XMLDocObj = new XMLFileManager();
                doc = XMLDocObj.LoadXMLFile(strXMLFile);

                DateTime startDate = selectedDate.Date.AddDays(-(int)selectedDate.DayOfWeek), // prev sunday 00:00
                endDate = startDate.AddDays(7); // next sunday 00:00

                var vTransaction = from x in doc.Descendants("Transaction")
                           where ((DateTime)x.Element("Current_Date")).Date >= startDate
                           && ((DateTime)x.Element("Current_Date")).Date < endDate
                           where x.Element("TransactionType_ID").Value == TransactionType_ID.ToString() 
                           select new Transaction(x);
}



public void GetCurrentMonthSummary(String strXMLFile, int TransactionType_ID, DateTime selectedDate)
{
                XDocument doc = null;
                XMLFileManager XMLDocObj = new XMLFileManager();
                doc = XMLDocObj.LoadXMLFile(strXMLFile);

                int CurrentYear = selectedDate.Year;
                int CurrentMonth = selectedDate.Month;

                DateTime startDate = new DateTime(CurrentYear, CurrentMonth, 1);
                DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddMinutes(-1);


                var vTransaction = from x in doc.Descendants("Transaction")
                               where ((DateTime)x.Element("Current_Date")).Date >= startDate
                               && ((DateTime)x.Element("Current_Date")).Date < endDate
                               where x.Element("TransactionType_ID").Value == TransactionType_ID.ToString()
                               select new Transaction(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` object has a property `Month`, with that you should be able to filter on month. For week you could use the `GetWeekOfYear` in the `Calendar` class, read this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx